# Does using the same variable name at diffirent encapsulation levels result in defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I just wrote a for loop nested within another for loop that both use an int i as an increment and it looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout <<  i << ": ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

When compiled using MSVC itproduce the following result:

```
0: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
2: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
3: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
4: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
5: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
6: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
7: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
8: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
9: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

Should this code behave the same when using diffirent compilers are is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: That's not undefined behavior, it's called "variable shadowing", and it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it they should explain all out scope and name shadowing/hiding.

Comment: 1) Variable shadowing is defined by the standard. Maybe someone else find a standard quote for it. 2) "_encapsulation levels_" Technically it's "scoping". "Encapsulation" refers to different concept.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius -- "variable shadowing" is not defined by the standard. The string "shadow" is not used anywhere.

Comment: @PeteBecker I could swear that I saw it there. Now, I am intrigued, about the wording used in the standard.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius -- sorry, should have been more complete. it's all about **scope**, **name lookup**, and **name hiding**. "Shadowing" is informal.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius [They call it hiding](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.hiding)

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you. I was too lazy to look through the standard, to find the quote talking about it, but the fact, that I was mistaken, about the actual term used, made me look for it, in the standard, anyways.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. I was mistaken, about the term used there, due to the word "shadowing" being ingrained in my mind :/